# Visualising assortativity in networks

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

[Assortativity and disassortativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assortativity) are graph properties that represent how hub-and-spoke-like a graph is, where assortative graphs have hubs that connect to each other, while disassortative graphs have hubs which tend to connected only to low degree nodes (see the figure below).

Seeing a transition visually from  assortativity to disassortativity can be important. Can Mathematica do this with a graph layout that highlights these features?

[image]

Comment: I think you should specify more precisely what exactly you want. For example, if you just want to color the vertices by ther degree, you can use `g = UndirectedGraph[RandomTree[15], 
   GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]; GraphPlot[g, VertexSize -> 1/2, VertexStyle -> Thread[VertexList@g -> ColorData["SiennaTones"] /@ (1 - Normalize[VertexDegree@g, Max])]]` But if you actually want the algorithm to decide whether the network is assortative or disassortative, you should check [`GraphAssortativity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphAssortativity.html).

Comment: I suppose I'm looking for a graph layout that will provide some good visualization of assortativity. Maybe colouring the edges based on the correlation of the degree of their endpoints might be good.

Comment: In that case, please include an example of your graph in the question.

Comment: Just a random graph is fine, for example `RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[100, 4]]`

Answer (score 3):

For the style, you could do the following:

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "ZacharyKarateClub"}];

vdeg = VertexDegree[g];
vstyle1 = 
  Blend[{Orange, Darker[Red]}, #] & /@ Rescale[VertexDegree[g]];
vstyle2 = 
  Blend[{LightBlue, Darker[Blue]}, #] & /@ Rescale[VertexDegree[g]];
hdeg = Pick[VertexList[g], vdeg, 
   Alternatives @@ Keys[KeySort[Counts[vdeg]][[-4 ;;]]]];

Row[Graph[g, 
    BaseStyle -> {Opacity[1], Thickness[.006], Black, 
      EdgeForm[{Opacity[1], Thickness[.006]}]}, 
    VertexStyle -> Thread[VertexList[g] -> #], 
    VertexLabels -> 
     Thread[VertexList[g] -> Thread[Placed[vdeg, Center]]], 
    VertexSize -> .16 {1, 1}, 
    VertexLabelStyle -> {Directive[Bold, 11], 
      Sequence @@ Thread[hdeg -> Directive[Bold, 12, White]]}, 
    GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding", 
    ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {vstyle1, vstyle2}]
```

[image]